# What this art style/trend is called?

Tags: interface-design, style-identification, trends

I'm noticing a trend for last few months in UI section. The components have either pastel colours or very contrasting coulours, hard shadow (no blur), dark outlines, hand-drawn type icons. The whole look gives subtle wireframe feeling. Figma, Scrimba, and Notion have used these in past. Does this trend /style have a name? I tried searching for retro wireframe style, but it was not that.
Examples:

https://dribbble.com/shots/12947468-Travel-Diary-Concept

https://projector.com/home

[image: https://projector.com/home]

https://dribbble.com/shots/9099886-Subscription-UI
https://www.figma.com/community/file/833515051385038928

Lastly, this website is not exactly like the above examples, has a lots of retro elements, but it's close. https://www.flowmingo.co/

Comment: Simply appears to be minimalism to me.

Comment: "illustrative"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this has a specific name. But if you want to search similar stuff for inspiration or exploration or for references, following can help:

**About the illustration/icons:**

If you search online for *outline illustration* / *line illustration*, you'd find some similar examples. Colors/fill can always be customized once you learn to make outlines part.

Similarly, you can search *outline icons* or *minimal icons* or *minimal illustrations* for icons part. I think it will show some relevant results.

**About the UI:**

I think it has something to do with contrast. If you ever noticed on a phone or Windows OS, there's option for High Contrast theme. When you turn it on, you see similar input/output fields and buttons. So *high contrast ui* might give you similar UI results.

Also, sometimes, it helps to know the purpose of knowing the *truth*. It might help solve a problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to several sources, this style very closely resembles the brutalist Ui trend.
https://blog.prototypr.io/what-on-earth-is-a-brutalist-website-5-things-todays-designers-can-learn-from-brutalism-7fb52b163f80
https://blog.prototypr.io/what-on-earth-is-a-brutalist-website-5-things-todays-designers-can-learn-from-brutalism-7fb52b163f80
https://www.toptal.com/designers/ux/minimalist-brutalist-web-design

The designs that are actually surfacing maybe far from actual brutalism but resemblance is uncanny. It's quite possible that some creative designers hav taken inspiration from the brutalist UI designs and modified it into more visually pleasing "wireframy" look and the trend picked up.

Comment: I would definitely *not* consider this brutalist.